# Participle phrase; is the grammar correct?

Tags: grammar, participles

> Beatrice, nine, sent a letter to the actor **asking** for piracy lessons to help lead a mutiny against the teachers.

What does the *asking* participle phrase act as? Why is participle phrase used instead of multiple clause?

Comment: The statement makes perfect sense to me. What would you suggest in its place?

Comment: Yeah, I don't feel like I can even grasp the question enough to write an answer.  What does it act as?  It acts as a participle phrase.  What kind of answer are you looking for there?

Comment: act as a subject, object, etc. maybe I should use 'function as' or something else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It acts as a subordinate clause further explaining the action of the sentence (in which Beatrice is the subject, sent is the verb, the letter is the direct object and the actor is the indirect object).  I don't understand how you're posing "participle phrase" and "multiple clause" as opposing alternatives; the participle phrase *is* one of the multiple clauses in the sentence.

The entire sentence is quite grammatically correct.

Comment: I think a participle phrase is usually not considered a clause, because it can never have its own subject or finite verb.

Comment: @Cerberus: I'd be interested in hearing more about that, but it's inconsistent with e.g. http://www.ling.upenn.edu/hist-corpora/annotation/syn-sub.htm#participial_clauses.

Comment: A _phrase_ is different from a _clause_, at least in the traditional sense.

Comment: Well, yeah, but they're not alternatives to each other, they're constructs at different levels of abstraction.  In any event, my best analysis of that sentence is that the *participle phrase* in question is functioning as a *subordinate clause* in terms of its role in the sentence; if that's not how it's functioning, what is the correct answer to the question?

Comment: Or, why not multiple sentences? you know, there are too many verbs.

Comment: @lovespring: It's not necessary because there's nothing ungrammatical about the sentence.  It's an excellent example of using clauses that successively modify one another to refine a thought.

Comment: @chaos: Sorry for my late reply. I'd call it an attributive or adjectival phrase. A participle is an adjectival word; that is, it can function as an adjective in most situations. It modifies either "Beatrice" or "a letter" (that is for the reader to decide, and it doesn't matter). A clause is a phrase that can contain a finite verb and usually a subject. I know some people call participial phrases clauses: I just think it is not the way to go, and it goes against the traditional definition. I ask: what would then be the difference between clause and phrase?